# rufus/scheduler every sunday

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

I need to schedule a script using rufus every Sunday at 9pm.

I have the following in my task_schedule.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every("week") do
   puts("Emailing Unverified Evidence Items Digest #{Time.now}")
   ArtifactsController.email_unverified_artifacts_digest
end
```

Want to know what is the syntax for scheduling it every "Sunday at 9pm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as indicated in the readme (https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/), rufus-scheduler understands cron strings, like in:

```
scheduler.cron("0 21 * * sun") do
    # whatever...
end
```

On your OSX / GNU/Linux system, type "man 5 crontab" in a terminal to have a detailed explanation of that format.

Cheers.

(please note that rufus-scheduler's cron feature doesn't leverage the underlying system's cron daemon)

Comment: can this be achieved any other way except for using cron?

Comment: Of course, you could write an every job that wakes up every 20 seconds, and if "now" happens to be a Sunday 9pm, it could do the work...

Or you could start a job on the 1st Sunday at 9m and say every("1w") and it should work, except that it'd slowly desync...

The sky is the limit... Many ways to shoot oneself in the foot.

Let's get back to the serious mode, the cron notation is here to concisely say things like "every Sunday at 9pm", why try to use something else?

Please note that you could use the regular cron daemon on your system to run a rake task "every Sunday at 9pm".